# Unable to find an exact match for CDP version x in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hei there
So I recently finished a small script that uses selenium to visit a website and download a specific part of it as image. I didn't find any other way than using selenium. I am really new with using this api. Now the script works, on my windows and on my linux machine. But I have a weird error that I don't really get. I know why the error happens according to other posts I saw, but I tripple checked that all my versions match. Below I will post all the versions I use and the script itself. Important is that the script works and does the screenshot as it should, but the warning is still probably not a good thing right?
I am out of ideas to fix it

**Things I was able to find out**

I am pretty sure it has to  have something to do with my Jar file. The error only happens if I use a jar file on windows or linux. With my intelliJ idea it doesn't produce any error. Now I generate the jar file with intelliJ and I dont really know what could cause this. I tried to readd my dependencies and nothing helped. Any help is greatly appreciated

**Error output from my Java jar**

> Starting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41
> (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904})
> on port 42307 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully. Apr 29, 2022 8:40:21 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
> Detected dialect: W3C Apr 29, 2022 8:40:21 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
> WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 101, so
> returning the closest version found: 100 Apr 29, 2022 8:40:21 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch INFO:
> Found CDP implementation for version 101 of 100

**Part of my pom.xml. I generated the jar with intelliJ tho and not maven directly**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Code snippet from script**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "--headless", "--window-size=2560,1440","--ignore-certificate-errors","--disable-extensions","--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--log-level=3");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("somewebsiteurl (placeholder)" + code);
```

**Chrome version on my ubuntu machine (same on windows)**

```
➜  MRimagedownloader google-chrome --version                                                          
Google Chrome 101.0.4951.41
```

**And this is the version of chromedriver I used. Of course the windows one for windows and the linux for my ubuntu machine**

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=101.0.4951.41/

Comment: That's normal.  It will fallback to latest available.  Devtools CDP version (bindings?) come from the Selenium package.  They just added CDP version 101 (to match with chromedriver v101) 2 days ago in github, and I don't think that version has been released yet: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/devtools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
Apr 29, 2022 8:40:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 101, so returning the closest version found: 100 
Apr 29, 2022 8:40:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 101 of 100
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

---

### Deep Dive

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Presumably you are using the updated *Google Chrome* Version 101.0.
- Your are using *ChromeDriver 101.0*
- You are also using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.1.4*** where the release notes mentions:

> - Supported CDP versions: 85, 99, 100, 101

Everything seems in perfect sync and ideally should have worked out of the box.

However, I strongly believe the instance of *Google Chrome* pointed by *`MRimagedownloader`* is of version ***101.0*** where as the instance of *Google Chrome* used by *Selenium* is of version ***100.0***.

You need to upgrade the version of *Google Chrome* used by *Selenium* to ***v101.0***.

Comment: Hei there. Thanks for the answer! How would I change that tho? On my Linux system there is only one Chrome version. Has this something to do with some dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, using maven with vscode, but solved it after being hinted by what you wrote: "I am pretty sure it has to have something to do with my Jar file. The error only happens if I use a jar file on windows or linux. With my intelliJ idea it doesn't produce any error. "

When exporting the jar file, the GUI presents me with a list of elements, of which 88 were preselected, including these:

- selenium-devtools-v104-4.5.0.jar
- selenium-devtools-v105-4.5.0.jar
- selenium-devtools-v106-4.5.0.jar

This fixed it: I unchecked v104 and v105

Now I get this response:

> okt. 08, 2022 6:22:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder
> findNearestMatch INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 106